# adb emu kill - wait for emulator to be fully killed

Tags: scripting, android-emulator, adb

I am trying to write a shell script that will an android emulator and reinstall an app (in preparation for an appium test).  This is my script:

```
   #!/bin/sh
   adb "kill-server"
   adb emu kill
   sleep 5
   adb "start-server"
   emulator "@api-29" &
   adb "wait-for-device"
   adb install -r com.mycompany.myapp.apk
```

The problem is that after executing `adb emu kill`, the terminal receives an OK message, which causes the execution to continue.  But, the emulator actually takes a few seconds longer to close.  If I add a 5 second sleep, then everything works fine.  But, I want to wait dynamically in the event of the emulator taking longer than 5 seconds to close.

I am EXTREMELY new to shell scripting, so I appreciate your patience.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try monitoring `adb devices` for the device list to become empty, after your `adb emu kill`.

An emulator goes through an "offline" state before disappearing from the list. During that period the emulator is still running, and will mess up other `emulator @api-29` calls.

Don't know how it's written in shell, but the sequence is:

- Get `adb devices` serial numbers
- Run `Adb -s [serial number] emu kill`
- Iterate till no serial numbers are found

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 #!/bin/sh
 start  adb "kill-server"
 start  adb emu kill
   sleep 5
 start  adb "start-server"
 start cmed.exe /k  emulator "@api-29"
 start  adb "wait-for-device"
 start  adb install -r com.mycompany.myapp.apk
```